# How to make AJAX form in Jquery 3.3.1

Tags: jquery, ajax

I updated my jQuery from 1.10.2 to 3.3.1 and have some problem with it. When i fill the inputs and press the send button my website just reload, and the information from the inputs add to the url of my website. It looks like:

http://egorlero.com/2/?name=Jack&phone=%2B7+453+453-45-34&msg=Hello

And there is no mistakes in console.

This is my html code:

```js
$(btn).on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
    lightFill(); //show fill inputs
    lightEmpty(); //show empty inputs
    return false;
  } else {
    $(function() {
      var count = 0;
      $('#request_2').on("submit", function(e) {
        if (count == 0) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var data = $('#request_2').serialize();
          $.ajax({
            url: 'mail.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
          }).done(function(data) {

            //some code going here if success 

          }).fail(function() {

            //some code going here if error

          });
        }
        count++;
        return false;
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts_original.js"></script>

<div class="request">
  <form id="request_2">
    <input name="name" type="name" placeholder="Your name:" />
    <input name="phone" type="phone" placeholder="Your phone:" />
    <textarea name="msg" placeholder="Your message:"></textarea>
    <button id="submit" class="send_button disabled">Send</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Can anybody help me to resolve this issue?

Although, fill free to test this form at the bottom of my website – http://egorlero.com/index.html#anchor5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues. Amazing if this used to work.

I believe you want to do this.

1. Use the form's submit event
2. disable the button if already submitted
3. ENable the button if error and possibly in `.done` instead

```js
$("#request_2").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $theBut = $(this).find(".btn");
  if ($theBut).is('.disabled')) {
    $theBut.removeClass('disabled'); // enable the button?
    lightFill(); //show fill inputs
    lightEmpty(); //show empty inputs
    return false;
  }
  $theBut.addClass('disabled')  
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'mail.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
  }).done(function(data) {
    //some code going here if success 
  }).fail(function() {
     $theBut.removeClass('disabled')
  });
});
```

Comment: Sure... Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: Thx a lot @mplungjan, I correct my code with ur fix